# Connector Version for Spark - Cassandra 3.x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

Can someone please suggest a version of Cassandra 3.x which works with Spark 1.6, Scala 2.10.5 WHICH WORKS!!!!

Below are the version of jars I am looking for the versions of the below jar files

Cassandra Core
Cassandra Spark Connector

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: Its 1. Cassandra Core 2. Cassandra Spark connector

Comment: There is no connector version which is officially compatible with Spark 1.6 (see [spark packages page](http://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), and [version compatibilty](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility)).  As far as I remember 1.5.0-M2 (spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.5.0-M2) worked just fine with 1.6.0 RC.

Answer (score -1):

Visit the below link for check version compatibility.

```
Correct version of connector is 1.6 for cassandra 3.x , spark -1.6 and scala -2.10.5
```

Check version as per below image.

[image]

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector